# Problem in Sorting Files by date modified in php

Tags: php

I would like to ask your help for my treeview project.
My problem is, the resulting list of folders is always alphabetical.
Yes, I want the list of folders to be sorted by modified time.

(Credits to Treeview for the listing of directory)

```
<?php

class TreeView
{
    private $root;
 
    public function __construct($path)
    {
        $this->root = $path;
    }
 
    public function getTree()
    {
        return $this->createStructure($this->root, true);
    }
 
    private function createStructure($directory, $root)
    {
        
        $structure = $root ? '<br><div><h1>' : '<div>';
 
        $nodes = $this->getNodes($directory);
        
        foreach ($nodes as $node) {
            $path = $directory.'/'.$node;
            if (is_dir($path) ) {
                $structure .= '<div id="body">';
                $structure .= ''.$node.'';
                $structure .= self::createStructure($path, false);
                $structure .= '</div><br>';
            } else {
                $path = str_replace($this->root.'/', null, $path);

                $structure .= '<a href="activities/'.$path.'">
                               <img src="activities/'.$path.'" width="250px" height="200px" >
                               </a>';

            }
        }
 
        return $structure.'</div>';
    }
 
    private function getNodes($directory = null)
    {
        $folders = [];
        $files = [];
 
        $nodes = scandir($directory);

        foreach ($nodes as $node){

            if (!$this->exclude($node)) {
                if (is_dir($directory.'/'.$node)) {
                    $folders[] = $node;
                } else {
                    $files[] = $node;
                }
            }
        }
 
        return array_merge($folders, $files);
    }
 
    private function exclude($filename)
    {
        return in_array($filename, ['.', '..', 'index.php', '.htaccess', '.DS_Store']);
    }
}
 
$treeView = new TreeView('activities/');
echo $treeView->getTree();

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update `getNodes()` to add the file modification time to the result set. You're currently only populating the entries' names, and as you are right in saying, `scandir()` can sort only on the filename. What you need is an extra call to retrieve the `stat` (meta) information for each entry, and store that alongside the name.

You can update `getNodes()` like so:

```
private function getNodes($directory = null)
{
    $folders = [];
    $files = [];

    $nodes = scandir($directory);

    foreach ($nodes as $node){

        if (!$this->exclude($node)) {
            $entry = [ 'name' => $node, 'mtime' => filemtime("$directory/$node") ];
            if (is_dir($directory.'/'.$node)) {
                $folders[] = $entry;
            } else {
                $files[] = $entry;
            }
        }
    }

    $entries = array_merge($folders, $files);
    usort(
        $entries,
        function ($a, $b) { return $a['mtime'] < $b['mtime']; }
    );

    return $entries;
}
```

And update `createStructure()` as follows:

```
private function createStructure($directory, $root)
{

    $structure = $root ? '<br><div><h1>' : '<div>';

    $nodes = $this->getNodes($directory);

    foreach ($nodes as $node) {
        $path = $directory.'/'.$node['name'];
        if (is_dir($path) ) {
            $structure .= '<div id="body">';
            $structure .= ''.$node['name'].'';
            $structure .= self::createStructure($path, false);
            $structure .= '</div><br>';
        } else {
            $path = str_replace($this->root.'/', null, $path);

            $structure .= '<a href="activities/'.$path.'">
                           <img src="activities/'.$path.'" width="250px" height="200px" >
                           </a>';

        }
    }

    return $structure.'</div>';
}
```

Comment: i will try ur suggestion sir ^_^

Comment: it says "PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$treeView' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST) in D:\Personal Files\TNHS\test.php on line 71"  -    $treeView = new TreeView('activities/');
echo $treeView->getTree();

Comment: That error doesn't seem related to my updates of your code. If you post your full code as a [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/), I will take look at that error.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: Good days sir, sorry for the late reply...  this is code that pasted in pastebin. heres the link. https://pastebin.com/embed_js/SByZMmd8"

Comment: That can't be the full code, because nowhere does it show the line you mention: `$treeView = new TreeView('activities/'); echo $treeView->getTree();`. Please show us the code that triggers the `Parse error`.

Comment: apologies i forgot the directory line. here is the complete code: https://pastebin.com/embed_js/WJCJP3xJ

Comment: You left out the `exclude()` method. If I insert that method and run the code, it works perfectly fine. You cannot have pasted the EXACT code you're running. Please try again but make no edits!

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: I apologize for the late reply sir but  i Get it now sir Ro Achterberg!!! I make another code and carefully follow your suggestions and Voila. Its working now!! ahhaah THANK YOU SO MUCH SIR!!! Im truly grateful.

Comment: No worries, happy to help.